# Help translating Reflector deconstruction into compilable code

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, unsafe

So I am Reflector-ing some framework 2.0 code and end up with the following deconstruction

```
fixed (void* voidRef3 = ((void*) &_someMember))
{
...
}
```

This won't compile due to '`The right hand side of a fixed statement assignment may not be a cast expression`'

I understand that Reflector can only approximate and generally I can see a clear path but this is a bit outside my experience.

Question: what is Reflector trying to describe to me?

Update:

Am also seeing the following

```
fixed (IntPtr* ptrRef3 = ((IntPtr*) &this._someMember))
```

Update:

So, as Mitch says, it is not a bitwise operator, but an addressOf operator.

Question is now:

```
fixed (IntPtr* ptrRef3 = &_someMember)
```

fails with an '`Cannot implicitly convert type 'xxx*' to 'System.IntPtr*'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`' compilation error.

So I seemed to be damned if I do and damned if I dont. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I think i have it figured. By chance I went back to the expression that was using `void*` and removed the casts and VS stopped complaining and since I gathered from the participants in this conversation that `void*` and `intptr*` are equivalent I simply swapped them out, resulting in this:

```
fixed (void* ptrRef3 = &_someMember)
```

and VS stopped complaining.  Can someone verify that

```
fixed (void* ptrRef3 = &_someMember)
```

is equivalent to

```
fixed (IntPtr* ptrRef3 = &_someMember)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is taking the address of `_someMember` and casting it to `(void *)` (i.e. a pointer address), and then setting a location to that address.

The `fixed` statement 'pins' the object, and prevents the GC from moving it around.

The '&' used in that context is the 'Address Of' operator, not Bitwise And.

In response to updated question:

Have you tried:

```
fixed (void* voidRef3 = &_someMember) 
{ 
... 
}
```

Comment: Mitch, I am more interested in what appears to me to be a bitwise operator '&' that is decorating _someMember. Apparently this is syntax that I am not familiar with. And it seems to be an assigment as opposed to a comparison. Again, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: It is not the bitwise operator when used that way; it is the 'address of' operator (same as in C and C++)

Comment: I suspected as much. So let me adjust the question. Thanks and sorry for the moving target.

Comment: OK, +1 and a check for answering my question as written. I guess what I was really after was a hint on how to express the same in compilable form. Can you help me along with that?

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your last comment: does this work for you?

```
fixed (IntPtr* ptrRef3 = (IntPtr *) &_someMember)
```

**Edit**

I'm not sure what you mean

> that is effectively what reflector
>   gave me

The error you mention seems quite clear: it can explicitly convert from (void *) to (IntPtr *) if you ask. My example asks, yours doesn't.

Are you really getting the same error message when you insert the `(IntPtr *)`?

**Another Edit**

> Can someone verify that
>
> `fixed (void* ptrRef3 = &_someMember)`
>
> is equivalent to
>
> `fixed (IntPtr* ptrRef3 = &_someMember)`

First of all: yes, they're equivalent.

Second of all: I've been thinking about what all this means. I think the decompiler figures it doesn't know enough to create a movable reference to _someMember, and so can't leave it to the C# runtime to manage it. To cope with this, it uses `fixed` to disable garbage collection for that memory, leaving it to you to tell the runtime when it's safe to deallocate.

Therefore this is not code you should keep around: as soon as you figure out the real meaning and lifespan of that bit of data, rewrite it to use regular (garbage collected) variables.

Comment: thanks for the response but that is effectively what reflector gave me and it gives the compilation error I listed. Unless the whitespace between `IntPtr` and `*` is significant? So apparently I do not know how to express the cast in a way that the compiler finds pleasure with.  I think therein lies the rub.

Comment: Reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is a .net decompilation tool that generates code from IL. Generally, it outputs compilable code but there are edge cases in which it does not have the smarts to construct the proper C# from the IL. And in those cases, I am usually able to infer the intention.  This seems to be one that, obviously, I am at a loss on how to express properly in C#. And, yes, the example you give is effectively the same as the  second snippet in my question that gives the same compilation error.

Comment: It is a given that this 'intent' is expressable in C# as the original source is C#, but the decompilation tool has done me no favors in this instance. I am no C# guru, but I, like you, have been pushing bits for several decades and it irks me when I get stumped by sytax. ;-)

Comment: I seem to have arrived at a solution. Would you mind taking a look?